# Unable to call scope.$apply from my code

Tags: angularjs

When I try to call $scope.$apply() in code below from 'activate' function , it throws an error saying $scope is undefined. **Is there a way to call this within the 'activate' function?**

```
(function () {
'use strict';

angular
    .module('app.reports')
    .controller('DeleteReportController', DeleteReportController);

DeleteReportController.$inject = ['logger', '$mdDialog', '$state', 'reportsService',
    'userPreferenceService', '_'];

function DeleteReportController(logger, $mdDialog, $state, reportsService,
    userPreferenceService, _) {
    /*jshint validthis: true */
    var deleteReport = this;
    var currentReport = null;


    activate();

    /**
    * @name activate
    * @memberOf app.reports.DeleteReportController
    * @description
    *   Activate Delete Report controller
    */
    function activate() {
        currentReport = reportsService.getCurrentReport();
        $scope.$apply();//THIS THROWS AN ERROR saying scope is undefined
    }
    }
})();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It wasn't defined, you have to inject it as a provider:

```
(function () {
'use strict';

angular
    .module('app.reports')
    .controller('DeleteReportController', DeleteReportController);

DeleteReportController.$inject = ['$scope', 'logger', '$mdDialog', '$state', 'reportsService',
    'userPreferenceService', '_'];

function DeleteReportController($scope, logger, $mdDialog, $state, reportsService,
    userPreferenceService, _) {
    /*jshint validthis: true */
    var deleteReport = this;
    var currentReport = null;


    activate();

    /**
    * @name activate
    * @memberOf app.reports.DeleteReportController
    * @description
    *   Activate Delete Report controller
    */
    function activate() {
        currentReport = reportsService.getCurrentReport();
        $scope.$apply();//THIS THROWS AN ERROR saying scope is undefined
    }
    }
})();
```